# Qualtrics Block form submit when press next button

Tags: qualtrics

When i click next button in Qualtrics survey, 
I want to block form-submit using javascript.
Is there any way to block form-submit not using disableNextButton Method???
Or I need your advice...

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    function myFunction() {
        var c = confirm("JUST for TEST");
        if (c == true) {
            this.clickNextButton();
        } else {
            //I need your help :(
            alert("alert");
        }
    }
document.getElementById('NextButton').onclick = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('NextButton').nodeName= "submit") {
        myFunction();
    }
};
});
```

Comment: I assume what you are trying to do here is to perform some function on next button click before the page is unloaded, is that correct?

Comment: I updated Qualtrics Onload Script. When I click next button, I want to block  form submit.